# Let T = {<M> | M is a TM that accepts $w^R$ whenever it accepts w}. Show that T is undecidable

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability

> Let T = {<M> | M is a TM that accepts w<sup>r</sup> whenever it accepts w}.
>   Show that T is undecidable.

I have two answers to this question - [San Diego](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp06/cse105/homework8.pdf):

> **5.9**
>   Let T = { <M> | M is a TM that accepts w<sup>r</sup>  whenever it accepts w }.
>
> Assume T is decidable and let decider R decide T.
>   Reduce from A<sub>TM</sub> by constructing a TM S as follows:
>
> - S: on input <M,w>
>
>   1. create a TM Q as follows:
>          On input x:
>
>      1. if x does not have the form 01 or 10 reject.
>      2. if x has the form 01, then accept.
>      3. else (x has the form 10), Run M on w and accept if M accepts w.
>   2. Run R on
>   3. Accept if R accepts, reject if R rejects.
>
> Because S decides A<sub>TM</sub>, which is known to be undecidable, we then know that T is not decidable

Undisclosed source:

> - **5.12**  We show that *A*<sub>TM</sub> ≤<sub>m</sub> *S* by mapping ‹*M*, *w*› to ‹*M'*› where *M'* is the following TM:
>
>   - *M'* = “On input *x*:
>
>     1. If *x* = 01 then *accept*.
>     2. If *x* ≠ 10 then *reject*.
>     3. If *x* = 10 simulate *M* on *w*.
>          If *M* accepts *w* then *accept*; if *M* halts and rejects then *reject*.”
>
>   If ‹*M*, *w*› ∈ *A*<sub>TM</sub> then *M* accepts *w* and *L*(*M'*) = {01,10}, so ‹*M'*› ∈ *S*.
>     Conversely, if ‹*M*, *w*› ∉ *A*<sub>TM</sub> then *L*(*M'*) = {01}, so ‹*M'*› ∉ *S*. Therefore,
>     ‹*M*, *w*› ∈ *A*<sub>TM</sub> ⇔ ‹*M'*› ∈ *S*.

But I do not understand the following:

1- what is the relation between x and w?

2- why we consider the 2 cases ‹*M*, *w*› ∈ *A*<sub>TM</sub> and ‹*M*, *w*› ∉ *A*<sub>TM</sub>?

3- why if A is mapping reducible to S this makes S undecidable?

could anyone clarify these points for me?

Comment: Please do not post text or code as an image; it's not searchable and can't be interpreted by screen readers. (You can use html entities for mathematical symbols.)

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What's R, and what does $w^R$ mean? What's $A_{TM}$? Is it the same as $T$?

Comment: @PaulHankin  R means the reverse of the string which means the same letters of the string written in reverse order.

Comment: @m69 okay I am sorry, sometimes I do not have enough time to write my question .....I am so sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is not suitable for asking in SO because it is not a educational website, but I answered it.

1- what is the relation between x and w?

> **Answer 1:** x is a symbol that used for using a symbol for operate. This symbol should not be in alphabet of language, just it. It hasn't
>   any relation to w.

2- why we consider the 2 cases ‹M, w› ∈ ATM and ‹M, w› ∉ ATM?

> **Answer 2:** For proofing a language like L is decidable or not, we need to determine a string like w is member of language or not. So we
>   have to consider two type of string w∉L and w∈L.

3- why if A is mapping reducible to S this makes S undecidable?

> **Answer 3:** It means the process of checking a string is in language in A and S is similar and if we can't find a algorithm for checking
>   this for A, we can't find any algorithm for S.